# Сохранение RichTextBox в rtf формат

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно сохранить `RichTextBox` в rtf формат. Вроде ничего сложного, но у меня появилась одна проблема. У меня в `RichTextBox` есть немного текста. Сохраняю в rtf файл:

`exRichTextBox1.SaveFile("zzz.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);`

Размер полученного файла как и предполагалось несколько килобайт. Но я еще в RichTextBox вставляю картинки.

```
exRichTextBox1.InsertImage(Image.FromFile("photo1.jpg"));
exRichTextBox1.InsertImage(Image.FromFile("photo2.jpg"));
```

Так же само сохраняю в файл:

```
exRichTextBox1.SaveFile("zzz.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

И полученный файл занимает около 25мб. Сами картинки в суме занимают 1,5мб. Пробивал одну картинку на 0,5мб и полученный файл занимает около 10мб. Короче файл в формате rtf занимает памяти в 15-20 раз больше чем должен. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Посмотрите ответы [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1405054/5045688).

Comment: Я удалил свой ответ, т.к. выяснилось, он не несет больше пользы чем комментарий выше.

Comment: А какая длина у свойства `Rtf`? Возможно, надо просто сохранять его в файл?

Comment: @Qwertiy Длина у свойства Rtf такая же, как и сохранённого файла. Как я ниже написал, это из-за того, что картинки в RichTextBox хранятся в несжатом формате.

Comment: @AndriyGoliyad, думаю, что не всегда, поэтому решил спросить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понял размер полученного RTF файла больше, потому что RTF сохраняет изображение в формате WMF (Windows Metafile), несжатый формат, из-за этого и размер такой большой. И единственный способ уменьшить размер файла, это архивировать его в rar/zip. Или сделать вот [эти](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/224663) изменение в реестре, и пересохранить RTF файл в ворде. Тогда размер уменьшится в 2 раза. А если RTF файл сохранить в формате ***docx***, то размер уменьшится в 4 раза (у меня так вышло).

Comment: Насколько я помню, rtf поддерживает png-формат, что должно означать увеличение размера в 3-4 раза по сравнению с картинкой. Значит вопрос превращается в "как заставить RichTextBox сохранить в нужном формате".

Comment: @Qwertiy Я немного не понял ваш вопрос. RichTextBox сохраняется в формате RTF. Или его можно и в png сохранять как картинку? Или вы говорите про сами картинки в RichTextBox в формате png?

Comment: Я имел в виду, что картинки внутри rft-файла могут быть в виде преобразованного в текст png-файла, увеличивая объём в несколько раз только за счёт преобразования байтов в текст. А преобразование в несжатый формат перед этим не является необходимым. Про jpg не уверен, но думаю, его тоже упихать можно. Собственно, автор же пишет, что такой же файл, сохранённый из Word'а в rtf, имеет существенно меньший размер.